# Using minizip in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, libraries, zlib

I've been programming for a while, but for some reason I just can't find how to do something that I know has to be simple. I want to create zip files with a small utility that does not require dlls or any other helper files. I found a few places that recommend using zlib and minizip to work with zip files. I just can't figure out HOW to use them. I've installed zlib, but I have no clue how to install or use minizip. Every thing I find assumes I already have my environment set up to use it and "all you need to do is use function X and voila!" I've been trying to find how to use external libraries, but I'm getting just as vague info that way too. Are there any books that might be a place to start looking? I'm all for educating myself, but I'm actually quite lost with where to start on this.

Comment: Not to troll too much, but you know that Java has [built-in bindings to zlib](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html), right? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout XZip on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/xzipunzip.aspx

If you don't want to have to use any DLL's, that is a way to go.  I've been using the 7-Zip DLLs with C# .NET programs lately.  The 7-Zip SDK itself is not fun to work with, and all the solutions I know of that really work require the 7-Zip DLLs.  However, once you integrate 7-Zip, you have ZIP, TAR, RAR, just about every other archive format integrated.  The 7-Zip format itself is my favorite as it generally offers the best compression.

For .NET managed code, the SevenZipSharp library makes integrating the 7-Zip DLLs a snap:
http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/